# string literals escaping tool for multiple languages

Tags: text-processing, shell-scripting

I am looking for a single utility to escape [strings constants/literals](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/String_literal) for multiple languages:

- C, C++, Java
- Javascript
- Python
- XML, HTML
- shellscript
- awk, sed

The tool should be open source and linux-compatible.

It should work as a replacement for `urlencode, urldecode, xmlencode, xmldenode`, etc.

Comment: For which operating system? Should it be free, or do you have a budget?  Please read [ask]